# How do I make my code Running LoginActivity.java

Tags: java, android, xml, authentication

Getting errors in setonclicklistener and View object

```
     public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            final TextView etUsername= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
            final TextView etPassword= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

            final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
            final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

            registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);

                        ImageView myimageview =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
                        myimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.farm1);
                }
            }

            );

        }
```

Comment: *`Getting errors in setonclicklistener and View object`* What error you are getting  can u share that error with question

Answer (score 0):

replce your code with

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

final TextView etUsername= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
final TextView etPassword= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);

    }
}

);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line,

```
ImageView myimageview =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
                myimageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.farm1);
```

in my opinion after moving activity stop doing UI rendering related to previous activities